# Clara clustering on binary data with R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a pretty big dataframe (~120k rows, 24 columns) on which I'd like to perform clustering with the *pam* algorithm. All the columns are binary variables, where 1 represents the presence of the attribute and 0 the absence.

I saw that a way of doing this with such a big dataset is through the *clara* algorithm, which is implemented in the `{cluster}` package. The problem is that on the documentation i see that `clara` takes as input:

> a data matrix or data frame, each row corresponds to an observation, and each column corresponds to a variable. **All variables must be numeric**. Missing values (NAs) are allowed.

So how am I supposed to apply the clara algorithm on my data?
Normally it should handle categorical variables since the *pam* algorithm doesn't compute means, but I couldn't find any useful information online except  for [this question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Cluster-Package-Clara-w-categorical-variables-td843236.html), which remained unanswered.

I could simply convert my columns to numeric in order for the algorithm to work, but I'm afraid this would not be the correct solution to handle binary data with this algorithm.

Comment: Binary data are 0/1. Unless you mean your data is categorical? In either case, more information on your dataset is needed. Perhaps show us the output of `str()`?

Comment: Yes, my data is indeed binary as it's a `data.frame` with 24 binary (0/1) columns, where 1 represents the presence of the attribute, 0 the absence.
I edited the question with more details and with a possible (but very likely incorrect) solution.

Comment: On binary data, usually **frequent itemsets** are much more meaningful than any clustering algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Anony, I'm aware of this - in fact, I already applied **frequent itemsets**. What I'm asking here is if there's a way to apply the _clara_ algorithm to binary data, regardless of any statistical consideration (moreover, I found plenty of literature which supports the application of clustering methods such as _pam_ to categorical/binary variables: it's just that I don't see how to apply this in R).